# Non removable and non editable custom property in MS word using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, word-addins

So far I've been able to set custom properties to a Word doc by using OpenXML with the help of [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff936167(v=office.14).aspx) .I want to make this property as non editable from word properties details UI. Is this possible? Also,I would to fix this as a permanent property so no one can delete this property.

Comment: That's not supported. You may want to use a document variable. Document variables allow you to store key-value pairs and work similar to custom document properties, but they are hidden from the UI. Others can still edit/delete them, e.g. using VBA code.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation

Comment: Thanks for confirmation